# How to add default array parameter to bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass an array of strings to my bash script that I want to iterate over. I want to set a default array in case the user does not provide this argument to the script.

This is what I have tried:

*test.sh*:

```
default_dirs=("x" "y")
dirs=("${1[@]:-${default_dirs[@]}}")
for directory in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    echo "$directory"
done
```

but running *./test.sh* or

*./test.sh "w" "z"* yields:

**./test.sh: line 2: ${1[@]:-${default_dirs[@]}}: bad substitution**

What should I do differently?

Comment: `(( ${#dirs[@]} )) || dirs=("${default_dirs[@]}") ` is one way.

Comment: `dirs=("${dirs[@]:-"${default_dirs[@]}"}")` might be what you wanted.

Comment: @cbakos : You can not pass arrays to child processes. Even `./test.sh w z` invokes the script not with one array parameter, but with two parameters (w and z). It is just that inside the script, you can alternatively access all parameters passed via the special _array_ named `@`. Note however, that `@` does not behave in every respect like a bash array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to the script don't all come in `$1` (and `$1` isn't an array which is why the substitution fails), so use `$@` instead:

```
dirs=("${@:-${default_dirs[@]}}")
for directory in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    echo "$directory"
done
```